# apt-get install hadoop-0.20-fuse - package cannot be found

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs, fuse

I need to install a "mountable HDFS". Searching around, I ended up with several tutorials:

- https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Mountable+HDFS
- http://xmodulo.blogspot.de/2012/06/how-to-mount-hdfs-using-fuse.html

(and other similiar)

They all start with `sudo apt-get install hadoop-0.20-fuse`. But this is not working. I get error: `the package cannot be found`. I am still new to Linux. How can I get my Ubuntu to find this package? (Ubuntu 12.10 LTS freshly installed. The only thing I did since then was installing and configuring  Hadoop and HBase.)

I also searched around a bit more and found this:
http://code.google.com/p/hdfs-fuse/

In the "How to use section" of the README file, in the downloadable tar, has instructions to install FUSE with `sudo apt-get install fuse fuse-libs fuse-devel` command on Debian/Ubuntu. That doesn't work either. The instructions in the README file seem to suggest that we need to install FUSE before installing HDFS-FUSE. I am stuck with this as well..

Please help.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 LTS, so pretty recent.

Comment: This question belongs on askubuntu.com. It has been flagged accordingly.

Comment: Did you add the CDH repository?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps for mountable HDFS:

1. Add CDH5 Repository:

   `wget http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/one-click-install/trusty/amd64/cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb`
   `sudo dpkg -i cdh5-repository_1.0_all.deb`.
2. Install `hadoop-hdfs-fuse`

   `sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install hadoop-hdfs-fuse`
3. Mount your HDFS

   `sudo mkdir -p <mount_point>`
   `sudo hadoop-fuse-dfs dfs://<NAMENODE_HOSTNAME>:<PORT> <mount_point>`

Now your HDFS is mounted locally at `mount_point` and you can `ls` to see in it and use other linux commands.

Answer (score 0):

Download a release from [The Apache Software Foundation](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/common/) and use one of these tutorials to install and run it : [blog.cloudera.com](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/11/building-and-deploying-mr2/) or [crobak.org](http://www.crobak.org/2011/12/getting-started-with-apache-hadoop-0-23-0) or [hadoop.apache.org](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.23.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ClusterSetup.html). I found these tutorials very useful. Good luck

Comment: No mention of fuse - he wants to mount hdfs as a filesystem in linux.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install CDH3 repository before running apt-get.

Note that the official CDH3 repository is only available for Maverick (10.10) or earlier.

If you want, you can still try that repository.

Check out for more detail:

http://xmodulo.com/2012/06/how-to-mount-hdfs-using-fuse.html